# Calculations using multiple columns in a pandas dataframe while simultaneously grouping by month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply calculations using multiple df columns, while simultaneously grouping by month.

I need help with some finding the best methods and syntax to do this.

For background, what I'm ultimately trying to achieve is to get from one df to another, so that the data is laid out in a manner that I can create a specific plot in matplotlib.

I have the following df1

```
WORK ADDED  MONTH   MISSED TAT  WORK ADDED TO MOST RECENT REPORT    TAT
10/08/2020  8          TRUE                1                         2
12/08/2020  8          TRUE                0                         2
03/09/2020  9          TRUE                0                         2
03/09/2020  9          FALSE               3                         2
15/09/2020  9          FALSE               7                         2
24/09/2020  9          FALSE               4                         2
01/10/2020  9          TRUE                0                         2
03/08/2020  8          FALSE               4                         2
```

and I want to get build the following df2 , using the data in the first df1..

```
MONTH   % MADE  %MISSED 1 DAY   %MISSED 2 DAY   %MISSED 3 DAY   %MISSED 4 DAY   %MISSED OVER 5 DAYS
AUGUST    66      0              33             0                 0                 0
SEPTEMBER 25      25              0             0                 25                25
```

I will explain what the where the data in df2 comes from the data in df1.

df2['% MADE'] = the % of TRUE in the df1['MISSED TAT'] for each month. I only have two months AUGUST and SEPTEMBER in this example but I will have all 12 months eventually.

For the whole set ignoring the month I could do something like,

df(2) = df(1)['MISSED TAT'].sum() /len(df1)*100

but I'm not sure how to separate that out to get the separate % for each month as I require.
I looked at the groupby function but I can't fathom how to link that with the above calculation. All very new to me.

The other columns all work in a similar fashion to each other.

df2['% MISSED 1 DAY'] = the % of False in the df1['MISSED TAT'] where the df1['WORK ADDED TO MOST RECENT REPORT'] is > df1['TAT'] by 1, again for each separate month.

Then next column is 2 days over, 3, days over, 4 days over etc, while the final columns is 5 or more days over.

Again I think a groupby may be the way, but I'm not sure. Maybe there is a better way? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It would help greatly, if you could give input data and matching expected output.

Comment: No problem, that's done now.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[0], format="%d/%m/%Y").dt.month_name().str.slice()
```

The output of `df.index`:

```
Index(['August', 'August', 'September', 'September', 'September', 'September',
       'October', 'August'],
      dtype='object', name=0)
```

Entire dataframe looks like:

```
August     10/08/2020  8   True  1  2
August     12/08/2020  8   True  0  2
September  03/09/2020  9   True  0  2
September  03/09/2020  9  False  3  2
September  15/09/2020  9  False  7  2
September  24/09/2020  9  False  4  2
October    01/10/2020  9   True  0  2
August     03/08/2020  8  False  4  2
```

Then you can make whatever you would like to modify.

```
grouped = df.groupby(by=df.index)
for row, group in grouped:
    print("---", group)
```

Printed output (Does not take into account column names!)

```
---                  0  1      2  3  4
0                                 
August  10/08/2020  8   True  1  2
August  12/08/2020  8   True  0  2
August  03/08/2020  8  False  4  2
---                     0  1      2  3  4
0                                    
September  03/09/2020  9   True  0  2
September  03/09/2020  9  False  3  2
September  15/09/2020  9  False  7  2
September  24/09/2020  9  False  4  2
---                   0  1     2  3  4
0                                 
October  01/10/2020  9  True  0  2
```